# Fanning out an "arc" of card meshes

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, trigonometry, unreal-engine4

I have `n` number of cards. Each card is `a` units in width.
Many popular card games display a hand of cards in the "fanned out" position (see images below), and I would like to do the same. By utilizing the following formula, I'm able to place cards in an arc:

```
// NOTE: UE4 uses a left-handed, Z-up coordinate system.
//  (+X = Forward, +Y = Right, and +Z = Up)

// NOTE: Card meshes have their pivot points in the center of the mesh
//  (meshSize * 0.5f = local origin of mesh)

// n = Number of card meshes
// a = Width of each card mesh

const auto arcWidth = 0.8f;
const auto arcHeight = 0.15f;
const auto rotationAngle = 30.f;
const auto deltaAngle = 180.f;
const auto delta = FMath::DegreesToRadians(deltaAngle) / (float)(n);
const auto halfDelta = delta * 0.5f;
const auto halfMeshWidth = a * 0.5f;
const auto radius = halfMeshWidth + (rotationAngle / FMath::Tan(halfDelta));

for (unsigned y = 0; y < n; y++)
{
    auto ArcX = (radius * arcWidth) * FMath::Cos(((float)y * delta) + halfDelta);
    auto ArcY = (radius * arcHeight) * FMath::Sin(((float)y * delta) + halfDelta);
    auto ArcVector = FVector(0.f, ArcX, ArcY);

    // Draw a line from the world origin to the card origin
    DrawDebugLine(GetWorld(), FVector::ZeroVector, ArcVector, FColor::Magenta, true, -1.f, 0, 2.5f);
}
```

Here's a 5-Card example from Hearthstone:
[image: 5-Card hand in Hearthstone]

Here's a 5-Card example from Slay The Spire:
[image: 5-Card hand in Slay The Spire]

But the results I'm producing are, well... Suboptimal:
[image]

No matter how I tweak the variables, the cards on the far left and far right side are getting squashed together into the hand. I imagine this has to do with how the points of a circle are distributed, and then squashed downwards (via `arcHeight`) to form an ellipse? In any case, you can see that the results are far from similar, even though if you look closely at the example references, you can see that an arc exists from the center of each card (before those cards are rotated in local space).

What can I do to achieve a more evenly spaced arc?

Comment: Your cards need to be rotated around the point somewhere in the lower part of the card.

Comment: @teivaz Changing the pivot point of the card mesh would result in a slew of many other problems elsewhere within the project. I've actually already thought about it and brought it up with my team, and they refused to make that change. So sadly, it's not an option. Also, it doesn't actually solve the issue of the leftmost and rightmost cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your distribution does look like an ellipse. What you need is a very large circle, where the center of the circle is way off the bottom of the screen. Something like the circle below, where the black rectangle is the screen area where you're drawing the cards, and the green dots are the card locations. Note that the radius of the circle is large, and the angles between the cards are small.

[image]

Comment: I kind of like this idea, because it would also give an accurate direction vector (from circle origin to card origin) on how the card itself should be rotated... The issue, however, is the X/Y scaling of the card meshes, which is important to note when cards are of `a` units in width, and we want a certain amount of space in between each card, but the value of `n` can (and will often) change at any time. How would you propose calculating the proper radius vs number of cards, generating the correct points with `a` distance between them?

Comment: (i.e., say we have 10 cards. The radius would need to be bigger, so the origin would need to be offset by some amount and/or the meshes would need to be scaled differently)

Comment: @RectangleEquals I don't think you ever need to change the radius of the circle. The desired spacing between cards translates to an ideal angle between cards. So as long as `n` is small, the value of `n` determines the angle for the leftmost card, and the other cards are spaced by the ideal angle. When `n` is large, the start angle and end angle position cards at the left edge and right edge of the drawing area, and the angle between cards is smaller than the ideal angle.

Comment: [Here's the 5-card result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMmCe.png)... and
[Here's the 10-card result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSInV.jpg).
Whenever cards are added or removed, the radius needs to lengthen or shorten in order to maintain the same proper ratio. Otherwise, 10 cards would be a *VERY* visible arc (with lots of empty space underneath), making it difficult to fit all of the cards on the screen. If I could mathematically determine the radius offset on a per-card basis, I would know how much to offset the circle's origin in world space.

Comment: As of now, whenever I add more cards to the hand, the radius gets larger to compensate, pushing the all of cards further upwards. Without doing this, that 10-card image would actually fill up half of the screen (vertically). This is also no different from previously mentioned card games; They seem to adjust the arc based upon the number of cards in hand.

Comment: [Here's some data that I've collected](https://pastebin.com/6EdEqzMq) after adding a card... each time showing the radius, world-space location and world-space rotation of each card. Notice how the radius changes, but sadly isn't divisible into an exact scalar value (so I can't simply `auto scalarRadius = radius / MAX_CARDS_PER_HAND`, and then apply that as a scalar value to find the proper offsets).

Comment: @RectangleEquals Normally, it's bad form to alter the question after receiving an answer. But in this case, since mine is the only answer (and a fairly brief answer at that), I encourage you to update the question. For example, I would remove "Slay the Spire" image (just to keep the question as short as possible), and add your 5-card and 10-card images. And add your updated code along with any relevant information that you've collected.

Comment: I've decided to just manually place cards at a static Z-offset, depending on the number of cards... So I make a 10-card hand, cache all of the card's world-space Z values, manually offset them by a visually pleasing amount, then store that offset in a hard-coded array and apply it at runtime. I'm certain that a more mathematical approach is possible... but we got the important bits done with your answer, and found a decent enough workaround to follow up with, so I guess it's all good.